# How to convert a nested json file into a dataframe in R and extract the values in different columns?

Tags: r, json

I am very new to R and trying to convert the below json file into nicer dataframe

```
json_file <- "path_to_json_file/file.json"
json_data <- read_json(json_file, simplifyVector = TRUE)
json_data <- json_data %>% as_tibble()
glimpse(json_data)
```

My json file `file.json`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "sessionId": "AV50BX6JXG5UN0UF",
    "lang": "en-us",
    "disposition": {
      "bestPath": [],
      "allPath": []
    },
    "nlpEntities": {
      "status": "Success",
      "message": "Success",
      "sessionId": "AV50BX6JXG5UN0UF",
      "lang": "en-us",
      "startTime": 1660813927150,
      "entities": [
        {
          "id": "2660",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "welcome to c",
          "normalizedValue": "welcome to c",
          "preprocessedValue": "welcome to c",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 6,
          "contributedWords": "welcome to c",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c  my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2661",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "cannot hear",
          "normalizedValue": "cannot hear",
          "preprocessedValue": "cannot hear",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 214,
          "contributedWords": "cannot hear",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2601",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "line",
          "normalizedValue": "line",
          "preprocessedValue": "line",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 252,
          "contributedWords": "line",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2559",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "line",
          "normalizedValue": "line",
          "preprocessedValue": "line",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 252,
          "contributedWords": "line",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2698",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "disconnect",
          "normalizedValue": "disconnect",
          "preprocessedValue": "disconnect",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 276,
          "contributedWords": "disconnect",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2389",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "call",
          "normalizedValue": "call",
          "preprocessedValue": "call",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 291,
          "contributedWords": "call",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2615",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "call us back",
          "normalizedValue": "call us back",
          "preprocessedValue": "call us back",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 0,
          "turnId": [
            1
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 303,
          "contributedWords": "call us back",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello welcome to c my name is christian direc spread for today may i know your name please hello welcome to c my name is christian expired for today may i know your name please im sorry i cannot hear any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "3594",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "customer",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "make",
          "normalizedValue": "make",
          "preprocessedValue": "make",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "customer",
          "intentTurnNo": 1,
          "turnId": [
            2
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 8,
          "contributedWords": "make",
          "detectedSentence": "customer: i wanna make a call complaining"
        },
        {
          "id": "2661",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "hear me",
          "normalizedValue": "hear me",
          "preprocessedValue": "hear me",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 14,
          "contributedWords": "hear me",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2601",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "line",
          "normalizedValue": "line",
          "preprocessedValue": "line",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 101,
          "contributedWords": "line",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2559",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "line",
          "normalizedValue": "line",
          "preprocessedValue": "line",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 101,
          "contributedWords": "line",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2698",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "disconnect",
          "normalizedValue": "disconnect",
          "preprocessedValue": "disconnect",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 125,
          "contributedWords": "disconnect",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2389",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "call",
          "normalizedValue": "call",
          "preprocessedValue": "call",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 140,
          "contributedWords": "call",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2615",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "call us back",
          "normalizedValue": "call us back",
          "preprocessedValue": "call us back",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 152,
          "contributedWords": "call us back",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        },
        {
          "id": "2661",
          "modelType": "nlp",
          "intentChannel": "agent",
          "entityType": "STRING",
          "asrValue": "cannot hear",
          "normalizedValue": "cannot hear",
          "preprocessedValue": "cannot hear",
          "valid": true,
          "channel": "agent",
          "intentTurnNo": 2,
          "turnId": [
            3
          ],
          "asrValueCharSpan": {},
          "position": 186,
          "contributedWords": "cannot hear",
          "detectedSentence": "agent: hello can you hear me mm hello can you hear me mm im sorry i cant hear her any response on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you im sorry i cannot hear any risk once on the other line and i will need to disconnect the call please call us back thank you"
        }
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "agentId": "11",
        "customerId": "44",
        "agentClientId": "Agent_07",
        "customerClientId": "77",
        "tenantId": "33",
        "organizationId": "185",
        "categoryId": "314"
      },
      "intents": null,
      "isChunk": false,
      "isLastChunk": true
    },
    "connectorResponse": {},
    "ruleOutput": [
      {
        "id": "3165",
        "modelType": null,
        "intentChannel": null,
        "entityType": null,
        "asrValue": null,
        "normalizedValue": "#Ghost",
        "preprocessedValue": null,
        "valid": false,
        "channel": null,
        "intentTurnNo": 0,
        "turnId": [
          999999
        ],
        "asrValueCharSpan": null,
        "position": 0,
        "contributedWords": "",
        "detectedSentence": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "3583",
        "modelType": null,
        "intentChannel": null,
        "entityType": null,
        "asrValue": null,
        "normalizedValue": "No Response",
        "preprocessedValue": null,
        "valid": false,
        "channel": null,
        "intentTurnNo": 0,
        "turnId": [
          999999
        ],
        "asrValueCharSpan": null,
        "position": 0,
        "contributedWords": "",
        "detectedSentence": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "3584",
        "modelType": null,
        "intentChannel": null,
        "entityType": null,
        "asrValue": null,
        "normalizedValue": "Bug fixed",
        "preprocessedValue": null,
        "valid": false,
        "channel": null,
        "intentTurnNo": 0,
        "turnId": [
          999999
        ],
        "asrValueCharSpan": null,
        "position": 0,
        "contributedWords": "",
        "detectedSentence": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "3582",
        "modelType": null,
        "intentChannel": null,
        "entityType": null,
        "asrValue": null,
        "normalizedValue": "#Ghost",
        "preprocessedValue": null,
        "valid": false,
        "channel": null,
        "intentTurnNo": 0,
        "turnId": [
          999999
        ],
        "asrValueCharSpan": null,
        "position": 0,
        "contributedWords": "",
        "detectedSentence": ""
      }
    ],
    "summary": {
      "format": "bulletPoint",
      "templateId": 271,
      "bullet": [
        "Issue -  No Response",
        "Resolution -  Bug fixed",
        "Hashtags -  #Ghost",
        "Primary Intent -  #Ghost"
      ],
      "paragraph": null
    }
  },
  "errors": ""
}
```

Json file has two different main keys `data` and `error`. `data` key has some data in it while `error` key is completely empty

I want extract specially only `bullet` key values from `summary` key which is in `data` key.

My desired output should look like:

```
 Issue         Resolution    Hashtags  Primary Intent
 No Response   Bug fixed     #Ghost      #Ghost
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should give you the desired output:

```r
library(rjson)
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

data <- fromJSON(file = "file.json")

df <- data.frame(str_split(data$data$summary$bullet, pattern = " -  ")) %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>